# Networking error with multiple docker containers running in parallel

Tags: docker, gnu-parallel, mongodb

I have a number of python files containing unit tests in the directory `/code/test` In an effort to parallelize my test running without any code editing, I figured I could use GNU Parallel to run `N` files at a time against `N` databases. First I spin up the databases:

```
$ docker run -d --name redis-unittest-1 redis \
 && docker run -d --name mongo-unittest-1 mongo:3.2.10 \
 && docker run -d --name redis-unittest-2 redis \
 && docker run -d --name mongo-unittest-2 mongo:3.2.10 \
 && docker run -d --name redis-unittest-3 redis \
 && docker run -d --name mongo-unittest-3 mongo:3.2.10 \
 && docker run -d --name redis-unittest-4 redis \
 && docker run -d --name mongo-unittest-4 mongo:3.2.10 \
 && docker run -d --name redis-unittest-5 redis \
 && docker run -d --name mongo-unittest-5 mongo:3.2.10 \
 && docker run -d --name redis-unittest-6 redis \
 && docker run -d --name mongo-unittest-6 mongo:3.2.10 \
 && docker run -d --name redis-unittest-7 redis \
 && docker run -d --name mongo-unittest-7 mongo:3.2.10 \
 && docker run -d --name redis-unittest-8 redis \
 && docker run -d --name mongo-unittest-8 mongo:3.2.10
```

Then use `find` to grab all the test file names, and pipe that into Parallel.

```
docker run test_img find /code/test -name "test*.py" \
| parallel -j8 \
docker run --rm \
--link mongo-unittest-{%}:db --link redis-unittest-{%}:redis \
-v $(pwd)/test-reports:/code/test-reports \
test_img python /code/test/discover.py --file {}
```

This all seems to go fine, but *sometimes* one of the files will fail like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/test/server/testApplicationAPI.py", line 28, in setUp
    super(TestApplicationAPI, self).setUp()
  File "/code/test/server/tools/testutils.py", line 345, in setUp
    self.app = server.createApp(True)
  File "/code/server/util/rq/../../server.py", line 55, in createApp
    mongo = PyMongo(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, config_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 249, in init_app
    cx = connection_cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 428, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
ConnectionFailure: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I'm not sure how to begin troubleshooting this. Maybe something like strace to see what's happening in more detail? I've never really used that though. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it happen if you do not run it in parallel? I.e. -j1.

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have found a race condition bug in MongoDB. From the message it sounds like DNS being overloaded, but it might very well be something else.

You should now:

- See if you can reproduce the error in the newest code from MongoDB (The bug might be well-known and fixed already).
- See if you can make an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This is often very hard when the bug is a race condition - especially since you want the developers to be able to reproduce your exact situation. If you can provoke the error on a virtual machine from OsBoxes.org it is a good start. Varying the number of jobs in parallel and the number of cores on the virtual machine can help, too. Maybe some helpful people in the Mongo-community can guide you?
- File a bug-report.

Nothing so far suggests a problem in GNU Parallel.